# How to make a URL connection to localhost:8080 and check if the HTTP Response code is between 200 and 209?

Tags: java

I have been struggling to get answer for this question.

How to make a URL connection to localhost:8080 and check if the HTTP Response code is between 200 and 209?

Comment: What is your specific problem? Did you take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int code = connection.getResponseCode();
if (code>=200 && code <= 209){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to open a socket and send a HTTP command: `GET / HTTP 1.0`, and analyze the HTTP response to find the response code.

There is a simpler way, using a library like [HTTPUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/).